# Mysql service won't start, InnoDB init function error

Tags: database, wordpress, innodb, mysql

So seemingly out of nowhere tonight, my wordpress site went down and I've traced it to problems with mysql. Mysql won't start on the server because it keeps failing.

Here is what I'm getting from the logs:

```
140226 08:54:11 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140226 08:58:20 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140226  8:58:20 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140226  8:58:20 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140226  8:58:20 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140226  8:58:20 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140226  8:58:20 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/dev/shm/mysql/ibOqUOjF' (Errcode: 2)
140226  8:58:20  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
140226  8:58:20 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140226  8:58:20 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140226  8:58:20 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140226  8:58:20 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I've tried Googling and looking here on Stack Overflow, but I can't seem to find many solutions except to delete the ipdata1 and log files which, as I've read, shouldn't be done with stored data because it would mess up my tables.

This is on an NGINX CentOS 6 server.

Any ideas? I appreciate the help!

Comment: It seems that permission issue on `/dev/shm/mysql/`

Comment: AFAIK System error: 2 = No such file or directory - does the directory exist? Does mysql have permission to write to it? Is there enough space left on the disk?

Comment: @AbdulManaf Duh.. I set those permissions and now it starts, but the site is still 404'ing. This is also in the log: `Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306` which doesn't seem like it's connecting to the right hostname.

Comment: @Jon You were spot on. The directory did not exist, so I created it and applied the permissions to mysql. That has allowed mysql to start, however, the site is still not functioning...

Comment: @evan3168 You need to bind to `0.0.0.0` if you want external access to your database. So MySQL is running, but Nginx is giving you 404 errors? What do the Nginx logs say?

Comment: The same here. I changed the TMP and TEMP env variables, because I had permission problems related to them. Maybe that is causing this. In another topic I read that mysql does not like space in the path, but I try to avoid reinstalling it completely.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK System error: 2 = No such file or directory.

Check that the directory exist, that mysql has permission to write to it and that there enough space left on the disk.

Comment: So the directory definitely exists. I've given 776 permission to mysql:mysql. I rebooted the server and now it won't start at all. Even with the directory and permissions fixed. NGINX error logs don't show anything recent.

Comment: The logs were saying the same thing, but it wasn't starting. I managed to get in touch with my sysadmin who fixed the issue, but hasn't yet briefed me on the cause. I'll make sure to followup here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Another consideration might be to ensure your tmpdir used for mysql has enough disk space and required permission.

In addition, ***for windows users***: consider using `front slash (/)` as against `back slash (\)` for your ***tmpdir*** path

Comment: Thank god! I fought with this forever, I use SSD Caching and MUST specify the Windows tmpdir!

Comment: Double back slash can also be used, since a single one is used as an escape character.