# mysql server is getting aborted when trying to start

Tags: mysql

```
2017-04-14T13:48:19.151793Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-04-14T13:48:19.167419Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
2017-04-14T13:48:19.183044Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2017-04-14T13:48:19.183044Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-04-14T13:48:19.183044Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-04-14T13:48:19.183044Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-04-14T13:48:19.183044Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

This is the error shown when i tried to start my MySQL57 server. Tried to fix the error my setting by adding the following in `my.ini` file:

```
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
```

Still the server gets aborted. Can anyone help me fixing this?

Comment: `errno: 2` means "No such file or directory". Some file or directory that the database requires is missing.

Comment: it has nothing to do with the timestamp, that's just a warning, not a failure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql service won't start, InnoDB init function error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036724/mysql-service-wont-start-innodb-init-function-error)

Comment: That's a common error when your disk, or tmp disk is full ..